# PassportJs Google OAuth2 Strategy error: TokenError: Code was already redeemed

Tags: passport.js

I am trying to implement login through google using passport google oauth2 strategy. But I am getting the following error. I searched for solutions but none of them worked for me.

> ```
> TokenError: Code was already redeemed.
>    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/home/venkatesh/Documents/Web
> ```
>
> Dev/Apps/myapps/user_auth_jwts/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:320:12)
>          at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/home/venkatesh/Documents/Web
>   Dev/Apps/myapps/user_auth_jwts/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:367:16)
>          at /home/venkatesh/Documents/Web Dev/Apps/myapps/user_auth_jwts/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45
>          at /home/venkatesh/Documents/Web Dev/Apps/myapps/user_auth_jwts/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:177:18
>          at passBackControl (/home/venkatesh/Documents/Web Dev/Apps/myapps/user_auth_jwts/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:123:9)
>          at IncomingMessage. (/home/venkatesh/Documents/Web Dev/Apps/myapps/user_auth_jwts/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7)
>          at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
>          at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
>          at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
>          at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:437:9)
>          at process._tickCallback (node.js:351:17)